# jQuery rotatable() in degree

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

Hi we are using jquery rotatble plugin for rotating a div

```js
$( function() {

      $('.new-multiple').rotatable();
});
```

```css
.new-multiple{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable@1.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable@1.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js"></script>

<div class="new-multiple">

   <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/322f808cb7a7e06d38ca4c8a441332fd?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
   </div>
```

But the problem is that it rotate the div using radiant option . But we need to rotate the div using degree . that is 0 to 360 degree. How we can achieve this

i tried

```
.rotatable({
        options: {
            degrees: true
        }
});
```

but this is not working

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_rotate)

Comment: @matt not sure how a Canvas rotation is relevant to a jQuery UI Plugin and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i need to get the rotation in degree  i converted the given radians to degree in the stop event

```
$('.new-multiple').rotatable({


        stop: function(e, ui){
             if(ui.angle.current<0){
                   var given_angle=ui.angle.current+2*Math.PI;
                }
                else{ var given_angle=ui.angle.current;  }
                var new_angle=Math.round(given_angle*180/ Math.PI)+"deg";
                $(".new-multiple").css("transform","rotate("+new_angle+")");
        }

    });
```

Comment: `ui.angle.degree` provides the degrees for you.

Comment: i will check this . that means  $(".new-multiple").css("transform","rotate("+ui.angle.degree+")"); ?

Answer (score 1):

If you review the docs at https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable you will see:

> `degrees`: starting rotation in degrees (default 0)

Therefore, you cannot use the option as you attempted. It will need to be a `int` value between 0 and 360, not `true`.

For example, if you wish to initialize the rotation at 45 degrees, you would use:

```
$(function() {
  $('.new-multiple').rotatable({
    degress: 45
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.